# Moving pdf files to parent folder from subfolder with variable names

Tags: windows, pdf, batch-file

I'm trying to create a bat files we can use daily to copy or move PDF files from subfolders (names of folder vary daily) to the parent folder.   I have tried the below:

First tried to just copy the files using this..didn't work

```
copy "Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops\*\*.pdf" "Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops"
```

Next I tried to make a list of the files to be copied and use that to copy them, the list is created by the files aren't copied.

```
Echo %date%      Sweep Time = %time%       File count = %cnt% > 000_testpdf.txt
echo.>>000_testpdf.txt

dir /b /s *.pdf, /O:N >> 000_testpdf.txt

set logfile=MSOffice_PDF.log

dir /b /s *.pdf,  > 000_testpdf.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in (000_testpdf.txt) do echo D|xcopy "Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops\%%i" "Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops%%i" /i /z /y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                               v - disallowed
copy "Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops\*\*.pdf" "Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops"
                                 ^ allowed
```

Wild characters `*` are allowed only in last part of a path in Windows. Next code snippet could help:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "_parent=Y:\Print OPS\Annuity Ops" 
for /D %%G in ("%_parent%\*") do (
  if exist "%%~G\*.pdf" (
    echo copy /B "%%~G\*.pdf" "%_parent%\"
  ) else (
    echo nothig to copy "%%~G\*.pdf" "%_parent%\"
  )
)
```

**Note** that above code merely *displays* commands to perform for debugging purposes. Replace `echo copy /B` with operational  `copy /B` no sooner than debugged. You could also remove all `else` branch.

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`for /D` loop) [Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)